# How to set endIcon as clear text with password toggle in TextInputLayout android

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I need to achieve the password field 'clear able' & 'password toggle' button like below the image.(In image I have implement it using image editing only :P)

Is it possible without customization?

[image]

Comment: what are you looking for? Please explain

Comment: I want the cross button and eye button in a single field. Is it possible with android-material version 1.3.0-alpha01?

Comment: I do not think it is directly possible. You would need to create a custom view to support this. As of default implementation, you can only set one icon by setting `android:endIconMode` attribute in xml.

Comment: Ok, Thanks man for the clarification.
I think that any input field should contains three icons i.e error Indicator icon, password eye indicator icon and last one is end Icon that can be anything.

Comment: Currently (1.3.0-alpha01) it is not supported.